# How to get around conflicting type family instance declarations

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, category-theory

I am attempting to make kind polymorphic category theory ala Edward Kmett's [Hask](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hask). When attempting to translate and modernize Functor Composition I am running into a problem where GHC thinks type family instances are overlapping. Is there a way around the following problem?

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
module Hask.Functor.Compose where

import qualified Prelude as Base
import Data.Kind (Type)

-- The Type of Categories
type Cat i = i -> i -> Type

-- Natural Transformations
data Nat (p :: Cat i) (q :: Cat j) (f :: i -> j) (g :: i -> j) :: Type where

-- Hail Satan
data family Any :: k

data COMPOSE = Compose
type Compose = (Any 'Compose :: Cat i -> Cat j -> Cat k -> (j -> k) -> (i -> j) -> (i -> k))

-- Simplified Functor
class Functor (f :: i -> j) where
  type Dom f :: Cat i

instance Functor (Compose p q r f g) where
  type Dom (Compose p q r f g) = p

instance Functor (Compose p q r f) where
  type Dom (Compose p q r f) = Nat p q
```

Errors with:

```
Preprocessing library for kpf-0.1.0..
Building library for kpf-0.1.0..
[6 of 6] Compiling Hask.Functor.Compose ( Hask/Functor/Compose.hs, dist/build/Hask/Functor/Compose.o )

Hask/Functor/Compose.hs:30:8: error:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      forall j1 i j2 (p :: Cat i) (q :: Cat j1) (r :: Cat j2) (f :: j1
                                                                -> j2) (g :: i -> j1).
        Dom (Compose p q r f g) = p
          -- Defined at Hask/Functor/Compose.hs:30:8
      forall j i k (p :: Cat i) (q :: Cat j) (r :: Cat k) (f :: j -> k).
        Dom (Compose p q r f) = Nat p q
          -- Defined at Hask/Functor/Compose.hs:33:8
   |
30 |   type Dom (Compose p q r f g) = p
   |        ^^^
```

The full unsimplified code can be found [here](https://github.com/mckeankylej/kpf/blob/master/Hask/Functor/Compose.hs).

Comment: This _seems_ like a GHC bug to me. The two instances of `Dom` have different kinds so they shouldn't be overlapping. You might be able to hack around it by making `Dom`'s kind variable an explicit type argument?

Comment: Yea that really hurts the usability of this library though. Im thinking I might open up a GHC trac bug then try to fix it.

Comment: I don't agree that this is really a bug - if you turn this into a top-level type family declaration, it'll compile fine, with the issue that kind evaluation only gives the expected result for the first form listed in the family i.e. if the 4-parameter form is first, `:kind! Dom (Combine ... 4 parameters ... ) = first parameter`, but `:kind! Dom (Combine ... 5 parameters ...) = Dom (Combine ... 5 parameters ...)`. This is expected behaviour when the family isn't injective. The kinds can agree.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?